# Java: MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5") returning null

Tags: java, jce

Java: Any idea why `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")` would return `null`?  This was working just fine until recently.

Comment: can you add a code sample of how you're calling the getInstance method? also provide environment & java version data.  Do you know if anything about your java install changed recently?

Comment: Without any code to look at we cannot help. Can you please post your code?

Comment: "*This was working just fine until recently.*"..and what happened recently?

Comment: You must provide some code and explain what exactly went wrong.

Comment: That is the exact code:
MessageDigest lDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

Comment: @mre - Good question.  I'm trying to find out but so far nothing seems to have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt about the question

> MessageDigest.getInstance(“MD5”) returning null

If the class `MessageDigest` you meant is `java.security.MessageDigest`, that method will **NOT** return null, even if you gave a not existing algorithm as parameter.

The code from jdk1.7

```
public static MessageDigest getInstance(String algorithm)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        try {
            Object[] objs = Security.getImpl(algorithm, "MessageDigest",
                                             (String)null);
            if (objs[0] instanceof MessageDigest) {
                MessageDigest md = (MessageDigest)objs[0];
                md.provider = (Provider)objs[1];
                return md;
            } else {
                MessageDigest delegate =
                    new Delegate((MessageDigestSpi)objs[0], algorithm);
                delegate.provider = (Provider)objs[1];
                return delegate;
            }
        } catch(NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException(algorithm + " not found");
        }
    }
```

if it returned null, then md or delegate must be null, then NPE happened in this class.

so check and debug your codes step by step, find out which object is null.

Comment: Kent - I was going off of line number in the error log but after debugging it seems it was the line right underneath it.  So the question is no longer valid.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.